# Using external ISP/ipv4 allocation for home-based VPS

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, vps, wireguard

I am wondering if it is possible to connect/vpn my host machine to an external service that would allow more public IP allocation.

I have looked through countless sources and articles and the closest I could find was a wireguard-mesh through Netmaker, however through further reading a solution was not found. The only solution that seems to work is to buy a separate VPS and route all traffic to the VPS through wireguard which works however, I am unable to automate the process. There must be a solution/service that would allow me to assign public IPV4's to VM's automatically. I know there's existing ones such as a commercial co-locations which would provide commercial ISP's that would provide me with such addresses. However as a university student, I don't have the $300/month that it would cost for such service.

I understand I may be banging my head against a rock just for no solutions but I am still hopeful. If anyone has an answer, I would be more than thankful.

Comment: There is such a service. It's ISPs that offer it, at a high price. The other alternative is to hack something together using a tunneling protocol and virtual machines.

Comment: Generally it is really hard to persuade an ISP to give you a ipv4 range, that you can use for your home datacenter. It is cheaper and easier just to rent the required servers in an existing datacenter og just connect to them via VPN as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You don't dig a quarry in your backyard, and you don't create a datacenter in your closet. And if you still do, this means you build a server room with air conditioning, get a 19" rack, fill it with switches and servers, plug in at least two (for redundancy) decent WAN channels using optics, get a block of public IPs and an AS, set up the BGPv4 link to the upstreams, set up the hypervisors and vSwitches - and voila, you have it: first home-based datacenter. And a bunch of electricity bills.

But mom will argue. She will probably say that you don't dig a dammit quarry in your backyard. Because you don't need a quarry there: it's big, and noisy, and large lorries will destroy your lawn.

Comment: There are actually people who want to do non-typical things from home... often IT pros. Your comment had lots of words but very little content and didn't really attempt to help the person with their question, which is legit.

Comment: Oh, it does. But it takes some serious time to appreciate answers like this one.